# How to prevent table cell content from being wrapped at hyphen in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, word-wrap

My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main style="border: thin solid gray; width: 20em">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>0000-0000</td>
          <td>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            Aliquam eget diam ex.
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the output in Firefox:

[image]

Here is the output in Chrome:

[image]

In Chrome, the content of the first column (`0000-0000`) has been broken into two lines. Why does Chrome do that when Firefox can render the table fine without breaking the content of first column?

How can I prevent Chrome from breaking the content of a table cell at hyphen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap;` to the td

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main style="border: thin solid gray; width: 20em">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td style="white-space: nowrap;">0000-0000</td>
          <td>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            Aliquam eget diam ex.
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I have to say that the solution is very counterintuitive. I would have never imagined that I need to look into `white-space` property to solve a wrapping problem that is related to hyphen, not whitespace.

Comment: The `word-break` css property is more used to define where you would like to break. `white-space` is more if it should break, based on how it displays whitespace, i.e spaces and tabs.